# Does having multiple hard drives slow down the computer?

Tags: hard-drive, desktop-computer

I have a WD Green 1TB hard drive. A week ago, I noticed that drive C: and D: are full. If I add a new hard drive to my pc, does this slow down my computer?

> General PC Info
>
> > OS : Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
> >     Processor : Intel Pentium CPU G2030
> >     Core(s) : 2
> >     Core speed : ~3Ghz
> >     RAM : 4GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Hard drives usually connect through the SATA ports (Serial ATA) directly to the motherboard and do not directly affect other parts. The only load hard drives bring to the system is power consumption, so the PSU (Power supply) is the only other component that has to work "harder".

Even external hard drives do not slow down a system.

Comment: But it may take a few milliseconds longer to boot up!

Comment: @HappyFace: If you wisely allocate usage, an additional drive may speed things up by allowing concurrent activity.